# Rally: Get the bar function

Tags: rally, portfolio

Rally has a new functionality "Portfolio Items" in the Track menu.

I like the bars with the percentage inside which you can see at:

"% Done By Story Plan Estimate" or "% Done By Story Count"

How can I use it in my customized app in Rally ?

Can someone give a small example ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This percentage bar is part of a new App infrastructure that we are building. It probably will be called the App SDK 2.0. It is currently in development and will be released soon. Check the [product blog](http://www.rallydev.com/productblog/) for upcoming details.

- Mark